# Postgres Get Other Column Value Using Max Window Function

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I am trying to return the row number at the highest close over the past 2 sessions. Here is a sample of the data I am working with.

| Date | Symbol | Close | Row Number | Max Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1996-05-10 | BRKB | 24 | 1 | 24 |
| 1996-05-17 | BRKB | 22.8 | 2 | 24 |
| 1996-05-24 | BRKB | 21.6 | 3 | 22.8 |
| 1996-05-31 | BRKB | 20.4 | 4 | 21.6 |

Using a
returns the highest close value over the past 2 sessions, but I would like to return the row number at this occurrence instead.

Here's what I would like the table to look like

| Date | Symbol | Close | Row Number | Max Close | Row Number At Max Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1996-05-10 | BRKB | 24 | 1 | 24 | 1 |
| 1996-05-17 | BRKB | 22.8 | 2 | 24 | 1 |
| 1996-05-24 | BRKB | 21.6 | 3 | 22.8 | 2 |
| 1996-05-31 | BRKB | 20.4 | 4 | 21.6 | 3 |

Any ideas? I have tried a number of workarounds / solutions to no avail.

Above.

`````
`max(close) over (partition by symbol order by date)````
`````

Comment: This would be the equivalent of the pandas .idxmax() function in python